# For your interest -- [is this an] etymology site?

Tags: discussion

I hope that the following would be of some interest to [here](https://english.stackexchange.com)

[Is there an etymology stack exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297523/is-there-an-etymology-stack-exchange)